# How do I add a delivery plan when I get thrown this error?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, user-permissions, azure-devops-server-2019

> TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to
> complete the operation: Hosted Stakeholder License Security Subject.
> The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: Agile
> plans..

I am both **Project as well as release administrator**

I have added the **Project collection administrators group to the release administrators.**

Yet I can't create a new delivery plan or view the already created one from another team member, because there's this error that prevents me to:

> Failed to load data with following error: VS800075: The project with
> id
> 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/0ddc0e80-e58f-40f8-99f2-16c231bd2b45'
> does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.

Pls someone help me out here

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels) you can read that you need at least Basic Access Level. Stakeholder access level does not provide access to Delivery Plans. To change your Access Level you need to be member of the Project Collection Administrators group. To set it up:

1. Go to your Azure DevOps home (e.g. https://dev.azure.com/myorg)
2. Click **Organization Settings** in the lower left corner
3. Click **Users** in the menu at the left-hand side
4. Find your own user
5. Click the three vertical dots on the right-hand side and select **Change Access Level**
   [image: Screenshot to explain]
6. Choose **Basic** and click **Save**

You mention that you added the **Project Collection Administrators** group as a member to the **Release Administrators** group. First, the **Project Collection Administrators** group has permissions virtually everywhere, so there is no need. Second, the **Release Administrators** group has nothing to do with Delivery Plans, but rather with Pipelines. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. But I don't have access to view the MyOrg page. Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you replace "myorg" with your own organization name? You'll need to do that first, I'm sorry if that was not clear from my answer.

Comment: There's no "three vertical dots". All I could see is the option to filter the users by "access" and AAD user type

Comment: Please check the screenshot I added to the answer. You'll need to hover over the user in order for the three dots to appear.